# This fuctions get injectivity in the intervals of the form $(k-1,k)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ $f(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t$)) where $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unit sphere, is a local homeomorphism. I know that $f$ is continuous and surjective in all $\mathbb{R}$. The problem is the injectivity, but for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ exist a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \in (k-1,k)$ and $f$ restricted to this set is injective and then I get the local homeomorphism.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: What is $f$? Obviously not every surjection is a local homeomorphism, since $f$ can be constant over some interval. Also your reasoning is not correct. At least not fully, first of all you don't know what happens when $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Secondly being bijective is not enough. It has to be a homeomorphism onto image.

Comment: sorry, i forgot it

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.  Now finish it by showing the inverse of f restricted to (k,k+1) is continuous.

Comment: how can i explicit get the inverse?